# Program only works if dummy char array is declared [C]

Tags: c

The following code will print to the file correctly if `char finalstr[2048];` is declared, however if I remove it (since it's not used anywhere) the program prints garbage ascii instead. This makes me believe it's something related to memory, however I have no clue.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    FILE *fp2;

    char str[2048];
    char finalstr[2048];
    fp = fopen("f_in.txt", "r");
    fp2 = fopen("f_out.txt", "w");
    while(fgets(str,2047,fp))//read line by line until end of file
    {
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<=strlen(str);i++)//go trough the string cell by cell
        {
            if(str[i]>47 && str[i]<58 && str[i+1]>47 && str[i+1]<58)//from 0 to 9
            {
                char temp[2];//to hold temporary two digit string number
                temp[0]=str[i];
                i++;
                temp[1]=str[i];
                if(atoi(temp)<27)//if it's an upper case letter
                    fprintf(fp2,"%c",atoi(temp)+64);
                else//if it's lowercase, skip the special characters between Z and a
                    fprintf(fp2,"%c",atoi(temp)+70);
            }
            else fprintf(fp2,"%c",str[i]);
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    fclose(fp2);

}
```

Input

```
20343545 3545 27 494140303144324738 343150 404739283144: ffabcd. 094540' 46 3546?
01404146343144 283127474635324738 404739283144 09 453131 3545 abcdefYXWVUTSRQP
2044474546 3931. 09 37404149 27 384146!
```

Output if `finalstr[]` is declared

```
This is a wonderful hex number: ffabcd. Isn' t it?
 Another beautiful number I see is abcdefYXWVUTSRQP
 Trust me. I know a lot!
```

Output if `finalstr[]` is not declared

```
?99? 9? 9 ?9999?9?9 99? 9?999?: ffabcd. ??9' ? 9??
 ((((.(( (((((.((. ((.((( ( ((( .( abcdefYXWVUTSRQP
 øòòøò øò. ø òòòò ø òòò!
```

I did notice that the first `if()` statement could cause an overflow, however replacing `<=` with `<` had no effect on the end result.

I really wonder what the explanation behind this is, and whether it's C specific or if it would have happened in C++ too.

Comment: Have only read first sentence, but am willing to bet money on a buffer overflow that *happens* to be non-lethal if you have an additional 2048 bytes of unused memory allocated there.

Comment: First of all, please stop using [*magic numbers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29), use proper character literals instead, and is applicable use the [standard character classification functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte#Character_classification).. Then for a big problem that leads to *undefined behavior*, the `atoi` function expects a *string* and as all C-string it needs to be *terminated* which your string isn't.

Comment: You call `atoi()` on a `temp[2]` *that is not zero-terminated*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is with the temporary string you're using.  It's not long enough to store a null terminating character, so you have an unterminated string.

Make the array 3 bytes long and add the terminator:

```
            char temp[3];//to hold temporary two digit string number
            temp[0]=str[i];
            i++;
            temp[1]=str[i];
            temp[2]=0;
```

Also, you're looking too far off of the end of the array in your `for` loop.  Use `<` instead of `<=`:

```
for(i=0;i<strlen(str);i++)//go trough the string cell by cell
```

Finally, make sure you `#include <string.h>` so that you have a proper declaration for `strlen`.

Comment: Adding a 0 does indeed fix the problem. However I've always thought that the last cell of any array contains a terminator, hence why it's unusable. Which brings me to the final question, would this happen in c++ too? I wrote a lot of school-assignment-tier programs and I've always assumed that on the n-th cell of an n sized array, 0 is present. I've used code that specifically seeks that 0 to stop execution. But all of this was in c++.

Comment: @aron9forever Yes, it's the same for C and C++.  The last cell of an array will *not* contain a zero unless you specifically put it there.  Using a function like `strcpy` or `strcat` will add one, but you're not doing that in this case.  In your case, the array `char temp[2]` is a two element array with indexes `0` and `1`.  You fill both of those, however the next byte in memory is not part of that array, so it could contain anything.

Comment: I've figured out what was going on. Apparently `std::cin>>` adds a null terminator after reading the input. That explains why it's always worked out for me that way, and why it didn't now. Thanks for the thorough answers.

Comment: @aron9forever `fgets` adds a null terminator as well.  That wasn't the problem.  The problem was manually building a string (`temp`, in this case) without also manually adding a null terminator.

Comment: Nitpick: The fact that he *didn't* add the null terminator means that `temp` is not a string, which is *why* `atoi()` fails. Every string is a `char[]`, but not every `char[]` is a string. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

`atoi(temp)` causes undefined behaviour. The `atoi` function expects a pointer to null-terminated string as argument, however you provided a pointer to two characters without a terminator.

The `atoi` function will read off the end of your array. Your dummy array influences this because it changes what junk is present after the `temp` array.

BTW you could use `(str[i] - '0') * 10 + (str[i+1] - '0')` instead of `atoi`.

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding, the problem is that the program fills the array potentially up to its full capacity by

```
fgets(str,2047,fp)
```

which means that the condition

```
i <= strlen(str)
```

works as expected only if the location after `str` is terminated with a zero; this might be the case when declaring `finalstr.`

Comment: `fgets` adds `NULL` terminator.

Comment: `fgets` always null-terminates the output (unless it returns NULL, but OP does check for that)